# Member Function Pointer Template Substitution Fails

Tags: c++, class, pointers, templates

I have the following code:

```
class A{
public:
    A() {}

    void foo(const B& b) {
       int a = b.a();
    }
};

template<class T, typename ... ARGS>
std::function<void()> * invoke(T *t, void(T::* fn)(ARGS...), ARGS... args) {
    //Create a new std::function on the heap to be executed later
    std::function<void()> *f = new std::function<void()>([=]() { (t->*fn)( args... ); });

    return f;
}

int main(void) {
    A myA;
    B myB(5, 6, 7);

    std::function<void()> *fn = invoke(&myA, &A::foo, myB);
}
```

The purpose of which is to be able to create a generic `std::function` from a member function pointer (and object pointer) on the heap for later execution.

My problem is, the compiler doesn't seem to be able to figure out how to expand the invoke template correctly and I get the following error:

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
inconsistent parameter pack deduction with 'const B&' and 'B'
```

I would like the semantics for my invoke() function to stay the same (i.e. object *, member function *, arguments...).

Is there a way to maintain these semantics while still allowing the compiler to figure out the correct template deduction?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I can get it to work if I do the following:

```
template<class T, typename F, typename ... ARGS>
std::function<void()> * invoke(T *t, F const &fn, ARGS... args) {
    std::function<void()> *f = new std::function<void()>([=]() { (t->*fn)( args... ); });

    return f;
}
```

However, this does not fully meet my needs because two copies are made of the argument instead of one. I would like only a single copy to occur when I create the new std::function allocated on the heap.  The arguments should still be passed in by reference to math the signature of the member function.

Comment: Why do you need `invoke()` at all? Especially since you run the risk of `myA` going out of scope before `fn` is used? Why not just have the caller create a lambda directly and then pass it around as needed? `A myA; B myB(5, 6, 7); auto fn = [=](){ myA.foo(myB); }; // use fn as needed...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that works for me based upon everyone's answers and comments.

In my application, I need to ensure that one, and only one, copy of the arguments to the function being invoked is made because that function will be executed within a different thread at a different time and the original data might not be available (e.g. a temporary variable on the stack). I had modified my code, as suggested, to use perfect forwarding within my template functions.  This helped cut down on unnecessary copies significantly, however, I was still getting an extra copy within the lambda in my invoke function.  It turns out, I had written the move constructor of my data type incorrectly so, when the lambda created a temporary copy of the data, it had to be copied twice.

Here are snippets of my working code (with my example datatype B):

```
class B {
public:
    B() : _a(1), _b(2), _c(3) {

    }
    B(int a, int b, int c) : _a(a), _b(b), _c(c) {

    }
    //Copy Constructor
    B(const B &v) : _a(v._a), _b(v._b), _c(v._c) {
        copyCount++;
    }
    //Move Constructor
    B(const B&& rhs): _a(rhs._a), _b(rhs._b), _c(rhs._c)
    {

    }
    B& operator=(const B &v) {
        this->_a = v._a;
        this->_b = v._b;
        this->_c = v._c;

        copyCount++;

        return *this;
    }
    ~B() {

    }

    inline int a() const { return _a; }

    static int copyCount;

private:
    int _a;
    int _b;
    int _c;
};

template<class T, typename ... ARGSF, typename ... ARGS>
    inline static void invoke(T *t, void(T::*fn)(ARGSF...), ARGS&&... args) {
        std::function<void()> *f = new std::function<void()>([=]() { (t->*fn)( args... ); });

        //Queue in the parent thread
        if (!t->_parentThread->queueInvokable(f)) delete f;
    }

template<class T>
    inline ConnectionHandle connect(T* t, void(T::* fn)(ARGS...)) {
        const auto lambda = [=](ARGS&&... args) { T::invoke(t, fn, args...); };
        return connect(lambda);
    }
```

I have also shown here another function, connect, which saves a lambda to be called later that in turns calls the invoke function.

With all this, only a single copy of the datatype is made as long as
a) The argument to the member function (fn) is of a reference type
b) The datatype has a working move constructor

Answer (score 1):

Your *invoke* function is already known as `std::bind` and if you want to ensure that parameters to foo are not copied, then combine *bind* with *cref*:

```
#include <functional>

struct B {
  int a() const { return 1; }
};

struct A {
  void foo(const B& b) {
    int a = b.a();
  }
};

int main(void) {
  A myA;
  B myB;

  auto* fn = new std::function<void()>(std::bind(&A::foo, &myA, std::cref(myB)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should really be using `std::forward` when dealing with parameter packs. Right now you are taking all parameters as values.

Secondly, compilation fails because type deduction conflicts between `void(T::* fn)(ARGS...)` and  `ARGS... args`. The compiler will get confused about whether to take types from `args` or from your function. For example, `A::foo` takes a `const B&` but you are giving it a value type `B` as well, which leads to a conflict. So you actually need two separate parameter packs to avoid this.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

// you didn't provide a definition of B, so this is what I had to come up with
struct B {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int a() const {
        return x;
    }
};

class A{
public:
    A() {}

    void foo(const B& b) {
       int a = b.a();
    }
};

// you don't actually need to create a function on the heap
template<class T, typename ... FARGS, typename ...ARGS>
std::function<void()> invoke(T *t, void(T::* fn)(FARGS...), ARGS &&... args) {    
     return [&, t]() { (t->*fn)( std::forward<ARGS>(args)... ); };
}

int main(void) {
    A myA;
    B myB{5, 6, 7};

    std::function<void()> fn = invoke(&myA, &A::foo, myB);
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use `std::bind` which does exactly what you are trying to accomplish:

```cpp
std::function<void()> fn = std::bind(&A::foo, &myA, myB);
```

Comment: I am creating the function on a heap because that pointer will actually be added to a queue in FreeRTOS which copies its data by value using memcpy().

Comment: In that case you could still just move this result onto the heap like `new std::function<void()>{std::move(fn)}`. This would be more elegant than forcing heap allocation in `invoke`.

Comment: For some reason, If I modify my code as suggested ([&, t]() { (t->*fn)( std::forward<ARGS>(args)... ); };) it causes the processor to fault at that point.  However, if I leave it as a lambda using copy-by-value and ARGS as && for perfect forwarding, everything works, however, for some reason, two copies of the value in args are made instead of one.

Comment: I ran this exact code and it didn't fail so I am not sure what could be the cause of it. It's hard to tell just from your description. No copy of `my` should be made at all, because the lambda stores a reference instead of a copy.

Comment: I actually want one (and only one) copy of the arguments to be made before the function is added to the queue because there is no guarantee which and when the receiving thread will access the data.  For example, if I invoke a function using a local/temporary (i.e. on the stack of the caller) variable, a copy needs to be made so that the data is available for the receiving thread.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments of `invoke` and arguments of your member function are *not* the same. One gets a const reference, the other does not. This needs to be reflected in the types.

```
template<class T, 
         typename ... ARGS, 
         typename ... ARGS2> // <---- !!
std::function<void()> * invoke(T *t, 
                               void(T::* fn)(ARGS2...) // <---- !! 
                               ARGS&&... args) { // you do want perfect forwarding
```